# Marking a row as removed or deleted: Is it a good design practice?

Tags: database-design

This is a theoretical* design question about marking rows as *removed* or *deleted*. I assume rows should be *marked as removed* whenever there is a need to remove the pertinent data, but the row should stay in the relevant database table to maintain referential integrity.

<sub>* *Theoretical*, within the scope of this question, means that it should not be related to concrete example and also not related to concrete relational database.</sub>

For the sake of the question I have chosen a classical example: A Shop's database. And a situation is: shop's user wants to quit using the shop and wants his personal data purged.

We have an `Orders` table which references a `Users` table. If we try to DELETE a *user* row, we will lose all referenced *orders* (assuming we have strong referencing). Therefore instead of a DELETion of a *user* row we may mark such row as 'removed' (i.e., have a `BIT` (or *boolean*) column SET to '1', e.g., `IsRemoved = 1`) and clear his `login, password, first name, last name` columns to purge personal data. This is a first approach, which I believe is bad. While we get rid of personal data, the row still occupies space in database - just for the sake of referential integrity: no other useful meaning it has.

But there is an alternative, instead of having an `Orders`->`Users` relationship, we can have a different structure: `Orders`->`Customers`->`Users`, where the `Customers` table has no personal data. When a *user* wants to quit, we simply DELETE the pertinent `User` row, but `Customer` along with its related `Orders` stay stored in the database. No need to mark row as *removed*, no need for additional business rules to handle the *removed* rows behavior. I believe this approach is better and may be used for any situation where the `IsRemoved` row approach is used.

#### Question

Do you think second approach lacks real-life application in some situations? Or can it be used for any DB design?

P.S. Of course, it is possible to referential integrity with NULLs in FOREIGN KEYs, however this approach is out of scope. While it may be useful in the Shop's example, the question is hypothetical, and *shop* is used only as example, not as a real problem (which *may* be solved with NULLs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd approach is interesting, but it seems like you could be optimizing the model for a scenario that is not that frequent (introducing a third table to be joined whenever you need to access the user data).

Also,  your description of the first approach seem to imply that the user table has no other info,  except the one that you need to purge, and it's not necessarily the case (e.g. you may want to track the insertion and purge date to have statistics for the leaving users).

Finally,  as everyone else has already said, there is not a single "good" answer.  For example,  you might have some audit regulations that forbids you to delete the personal data for a period of time,  so the "isActive" flag would be a better match.

Answer (score 2):

I think - there are no one "only right" answer
All depend from Your business model.

Normal practice for the data which we must persisted store - use isActive and/or DeletedDate columns.
In combination with DateCreated and LastModifed - it give You all information and flexibility. (including and Login table - it just not active)

But for some situation - real delete of data also accepted solution.

Comment: I think it is better to use history tables for the purpose of tracking row changes.

Comment: not always necessary - all must depend from business needs. For some events - good idea to have history table, but each time go thru all states not fast - so have DeletedDate right in table good. I meet this on many projects, so it often, but not only true :)